# How do I get back Firefox's mixed behaviour towards PDF files?

Tags: firefox, pdf, adobe-acrobat

My Firefox always had the following mixed behaviour with respect to PDFs: when clicking a PDF link, it would open in the browser, but after downloading the file to my computer, clicking on it from Firefox downloads list would open it externally with Acrobat. I liked that mixed behaviour.

Recently, it changed. Now, it always opens in Firefox, even when clicked on saved file from the downloads list. How do I get back the nice mixed behaviour? Changing Firefox preferences from opening in-browser to opening with Acrobat/saving/always asking is not a solution, since then I lose the direct in-browser capability for PDF links.

I'm on Windows 10 and Firefox 79.0 (64-bit).

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. In Firefox's downloads list, right-click the PDF file and select "Always Open in System Viewer".

Answer (score 0):

When you download a file and open it, it's the same whether you click in the download dropdown in Firefox or in the Windows Explorer. This is not a Firefox setting, but a Windows setting.

[How to make Acrobat Reader DC or Acrobat DC your default PDF program](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/not-default-pdf-owner-windows10.html)

1. Right-click the thumbnail of a PDF file, and then choose Properties.
2. In the file's Properties dialog box, click Change.
3. Choose Adobe Acrobat Reader and click OK.

Comment: I already have Acrobat as my windows default PDF opener. It works fine if I open a PDF from its thumbnail in any Windows folder. But they still open within Firefox if clicked on from the downloads menu.

Comment: Click on the explorer button instead of the filename.

Comment: You mean the "Open Containing Folder" button in Firefox's downloads list? That opens the containing folder, not the file itself.